# frankfurt beamer: add subsection to header navigation bar

Tags: beamer

My presentation has subsubsections, and I'd like to add the subsection name to the navigation bar so that it would read something like

> Introduction: Uncertain Optimization

as opposed to just

> Introduction

in the below example. How might I do this? Thanks!

[image]

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt, notes]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} % nice bullets at top
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,minted,float,multicol,mathtools,dsfont,hyperref,rotating,cleveref,bm,tikz,algorithm,algpseudocode,xcolor,vwcol}

% -------------------------------------------
% modifications
% -------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{} % gets rid of bottom navigation bars
\usecolortheme{rose} % lighten the headers
% \definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667}
% \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=UBCblue}

% -------------------------------------------
% setup
% -------------------------------------------
\title{A Title}
\subtitle{some subtitle}
\author{Some One}%\inst{1}}
\institute{Some Where \\ Department }
\date{May 27, 2018}
\subject{MWE}

% ToC command
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

% ===========================================
% content
% ===========================================
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

% ===========================================
\section{Introduction}
% ===========================================

% -------------------------------------------
\subsection{Motivation}
% -------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
  p1
\end{frame}

% -------------------------------------------
\subsubsection{Point 1}
% -------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
  p2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  p3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which code do you have so far? Please show an MWE!

Comment: I just am using `\usetheme{Frankfurt}`. I don't know how to access the header

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we have something to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code adds the subsection title to the section entry. You'll have to make sure that there are no frames outside subsections.

Some other comments:

- `float` and `multicol` don't make much sense with beamer
- you also don't need `hyperref` and `xcolor`, as beamer already provides this functionality

---

```
\documentclass[9pt, notes]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} % nice bullets at top
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,
%minted,
%float,
%multicol,
mathtools,dsfont,
%hyperref,
rotating,cleveref,bm,tikz,algorithm,algpseudocode,
%xcolor,
vwcol}

% -------------------------------------------
% modifications
% -------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{} % gets rid of bottom navigation bars
\usecolortheme{rose} % lighten the headers
% \definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667}
% \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=UBCblue}

% -------------------------------------------
% setup
% -------------------------------------------
\title{A Title}
\subtitle{some subtitle}
\author{Some One}%\inst{1}}
\institute{Some Where \\ Department }
\date{May 27, 2018}
\subject{MWE}

% ToC command
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\makeatletter
\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
  \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
  \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
  \beamer@ypos@offset=0\relax%
  \ifnum#5=\c@part%
  \beamer@section@set@min@width%
  \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill%
  \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
  \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#2}%
    \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
    \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
    {%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \ifnum\c@section=#1%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
        :~\insertsubsectionhead%
      \else%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
      \fi}%
  }%
  \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
  \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
  \fi\ignorespaces} 
\makeatother


% ===========================================
% content
% ===========================================
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

% ===========================================
\section{Introduction}
% ===========================================

% -------------------------------------------
\subsection{Motivation}
% -------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
  p1
\end{frame}

% -------------------------------------------
\subsection{Something else}
% -------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
  p1
\end{frame}


% -------------------------------------------
\subsubsection{Point 1}
% -------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}
  p2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  p3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For ancient beamer versions (version 3.36) try the following definition instead:

```
\makeatletter
\def\sectionentry#1#2#3#4#5{% section number, section title, page
  \ifnum#5=\c@part%
  \beamer@section@set@min@width
  \box\beamer@sectionbox\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill%
  \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
  \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
  \setbox\beamer@sectionbox=
  \hbox{\def\insertsectionhead{#2}%
    \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}%
    \def\insertpartheadnumber{#5}%
    {%
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
      \ifnum\c@section=#1%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}}%
        :~\insertsubsectionhead%
      \else%
        \hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}%
      \fi}%
  }%
  \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
  \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
  \fi\ignorespaces}  
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a compile error: `Undefined control sequence.
\sectionentry ...pos =1\relax \beamer@ypos@offset 
                                                  =0\relax \ifnum #5=\c@part...
l.73 \begin{document}` right at the `\begin{document}`. Any advice on troubleshooting?

Comment: @rrrrr with the exact same code from my answer or in your real document?

Comment: Your code which I just copy/pasted into Overleaf. Here's the [link](https://www.overleaf.com/16494523qvvnkwzkbztn#/63329603/)

Comment: @rrrrr Which version of beamer do you use?

Comment: Where can I find this? I just use Overleaf

Comment: @rrrrr You have to look into the .log file. If you download all your files, overleaf should give you the choice to also download all the auxiliary files including the .log file

Comment: `Beamer` appears in the log file a number of times, but my guess is: `beamer 2015/01/05 3.36`. Trying to figure out how to upload the full file

Comment: @rrrrr Wow, this is really old, not surprising it throws errors

Comment: Having trouble uploading the log file... and copy/pasting puts me over the character limit in the question

Comment: @rrrrr Can you test the above code fragment?